# Is there a synchronized way to validate models in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model called `TimeSpan` with a `start_datetime` and `end_datetime` field, and I want to do validation on the model so that no two `TimeSpan` objects overlap.

However, if I wrote code like below,

```
if timespan.is_valid():
    timespan.save()
```

then there could be a race condition where two `TimeSpan` objects are deemed valid compared to what is currently in the database, and then they are both saved despite being invalid together.

I could make a synchronized `validate_and_save()` method with locks, but that would break the Django admin. Is there an alternative built into Django?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use transactions if you head down this direction, however I would suggest that you look at your database's trigger functionality instead...